# JSON custom serialization and deserialization of existing classes in C# asp.net core

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, serialization

I have existing third party DLL - which has several classes. I don't have source code of this DLL.
Lets assume that it has Book class defined as below

```
public class Book
{ 
      public String Id { get; set; }
      public String Title { get; set; }
      public String Author{ get; set; }
      public List<Page> Pages { get; set; }
}
```

I have created Asp.net Core Web API project and referred DLL and wrote API Controller for GET method of http.

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public ActionResult<Book> Get(string id)
{
     Book b = Book.FindById(id); // This utility function returns Book instance.
     return Ok(b);
}
```

My requirement is return value of JSON should be something like

```json
{
  "id" : "1234",
  "Title" : "How to Custom Serialize JSON",
  "Author" : "Myself",
  "NumberOfPages" : 100
}
```

So basically, whenever JSON serialization happens, I want to ensure that `Pages` attribute is not serialized as it has many complications. But I should able to add new attribute `NumberOfPages`. Basically I want to take control of Serialization. I have seen many examples but I could not find this particular case where I want to custom serialize existing class.

I am not worrying about deserialization right now.

I can see that serialization starts from

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.JsonOutputFormatter.WriteObject(TextWriter writer, Object value)
```

Comment: I don't have access to source code of DLL. I cannot extend Book class so I have to use it as is. Meaning I cannot derived new Book Class MyBook from Book and start manipulating. In my ASP.net core Web API project, i have referred this third party DLL. I wanted to expose all functionality of this 3rd party DLL over http.

Comment: What if you just simply return an anonymous class, like this `return Ok(new { b.Id, b.Title, b.Author, NumberOfPages = b.Pages.Count}); `?

Comment: @Peter Csala - thanks for answer but I wish Serialization should take place thorughtout application. and not just for controller. What if some other developer writing controller or just directly calls JSON Serialize method?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this *"Serialization should take place throughout application"*?

Comment: What serializer  are you using? System.Text.Json or Json.net or something else?

Comment: I am using Newtonsoft.Json. Throughout application means wherever object is being serialized, same results should be returned. With your suggestion, I could serialize object ONLY during controller method execution .

Comment: Then you most probably need to implement a `JsonConverter<Book>` and register it to the global `JsonSerializerSettings`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to have a solution which works globally:

1. Create a custom converter
2. Register that converter

### Create Converter

The simplest approach: create a class which derives from [JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm):

```cs
public class BookConverter : JsonConverter<Book>
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Book value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var bookObject = (JObject)JToken.FromObject(value);
        bookObject.Remove(nameof(value.Pages));
        bookObject.Add(new JProperty("NumberOfPages", value.Pages.Count));
        bookObject.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    public override Book ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Book existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return new Book(); //TODO: fix me, now it is enough to make it compile
    }
}
```

- Here I have converted the `Book` instance (`value`) to a `JObject`.
- I have ignored the `Pages` property by calling the `Remove`.
- I have extended the output with `NumberOfPages` by calling the `Add`.
- I've skipped the `ReadJson` part, because it is out of scope for this question.

### Register Converter

#### .NET Core 2.x

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddControllers()
        .AddJsonOptions(opts =>
    {
        opts.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new BookConverter());
    });
}
```

#### .NET Core 3.x or .NET 5.x

In case of ASP.NET Core 3.1 or above the default json serializer is the `System.Text.Json`. In order to use Json.Net you need to install the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/) package. This exposes a method called `AddNewtonsoftJson` where you can register the custom converter:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddControllers()
        .AddNewtonsoftJson(opts =>
    {
        opts.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new BookConverter());
    });
}
```

With this approach all `Book` instances will be converted into the desired format when ASP.NET Core calling the serializer.

Comment: As I said earlier, i cannot modify Book class. Book class is in 3rd party DLL.

Comment: @Atul I've posted a revised proposal, please check it.

Comment: @pater. thanks lot. I tested and working fine. Only thing is I had to move my .net core 2.2 project to 3.1 . Do you have any solution to keep my project on .net core 2.2 and still make this work?

Comment: @Atul Yepp, in case of 2.2 call `AddJsonOptions` instead of `AddNewtonsoftJson`.

Comment: Smooth. it worked. 
           
            services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(opts =>
            {
                opts.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new BookConverter());
            })
            Thanks..

Answer (score 2):

I would take a different appoach:

- Create simple Data Transfer Objects (DTOs) for the public API. This way you can add what properties you want and leave out those you want to hide.
- Use Automapper to perform the tedious copying of properties between the 3rd party classes and your DTO objects.

For a better description of the idea than I'm able to write, see for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5

Comment: that is right. but i don't want to use this approach just because I am not able to serialize object to JSON. My goal is not just to make things work but I want to solve JSON serialization problem. However there several entities and their complex relation between. it will considerable efforts for me to create DTOs for all entities. instead, I want to tap only serialization of entity for specific properties that i know . Other idea is to write Custom serialization utility method explicitly and use those method to serialize object. that is what i am considering now.